# How to delete duplicates, but keep the first instance and a blank cell for the duplicates in OpenOffice Calc?

Tags: duplicates, openoffice-calc

If I have data like:

```
A          B          C
111        asdews     iujfhg
111        oikufjf    jasddaf
112        eifjfjc    olkdkj
112        eiejdj     olokjjfki
112        ioeiurjf   oleodks
113        oeiekdkd   poldkkmd
```

I would like to delete all duplicates except the first instance but keep the cell blank for all subsequent duplicates. The expected result:

```
A          B          C
111        asdews     iujfhg
           oikufjf    jasddaf
112        eifjfjc    olkdkj
           eiejdj     olokjjfki
           ioeiurjf   oleodks
113        oeiekdkd   poldkkmd
```

The only way I've found to delete duplicates is the standard filter that will just remove all duplicates. I can't do this since I have the other cols like B and C that have data. The reason I need this is due to the program I need to import and it will overwrite each line with the next if it has the same ID. Since I need them to append to the same ID, not overwrite, I have to somehow manage this task. I have roughly a million lines across multiple documents to do this with so a quick method is preferable if at all possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is simple enough in Excel VBA. Access the VBE by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> and insert a new module. Copy and paste the following code into the module and run it. **Back up your file first before doing this.**

```
Sub RemoveRepeatingStrings()

    Dim BaseStr As String, CurrStr As String
    Dim EndRow As Long

    EndRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    BaseStr = Range("A1").Value

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Iter = 2 To EndRow
        CurrStr = Range("A" & Iter).Value
        If CurrStr = BaseStr Then
            Range("A" & Iter).Value = vbNullString
        Else
            BaseStr = Range("A" & Iter).Value
        End If
    Next Iter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Set-up:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Let us know if this helps.